# Python - Catch run time of the file in specific Format

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I wanted to get the time which script was running.i have the following code:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
# codes here
print(time.time() - start_time)
```

But this gives in format:

```
Second.milisecond
```

I want to get it in this format:

```
D:H:M:S
(Day:Hours:minutes:seconds)
```

How can I get it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime
s = datetime.datetime.now()
#codes here
print (datetime.datetime.now() - s)
```

I guess ... (its not the exact format but probably close enough)

alternatively

```
total_seconds = 12354324354545
m,s = divmod(total_seconds,60)
h,m = divmod(m,60)
d,h = divmod(h,24)
print(d,h,m,s)
```

Comment: thanks.first method is near but i need the exact format as i said.

Comment: well that is the point where you put on your thinking cap and take this information and figure out how to make it work with your format....

Comment: i think i found the way by thinking.thanks for inspiration